# Random text after rails loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a loop to show all blog posts. I am getting an error that displays random text after the loop:

[image: random strings after loop]

It looks like there's a stack of texts with all the post information listed at the end of the loop, I have no idea how it happened and how to fix it.

I checked my HTML and CSS, but couldn't figure out what caused the issue.

Below is the HTML and CSS code:

```
<section id="posts" class="wrapper">
   <h2>My Latest Articles</h2>
   <hr>

   <div class="post_container">
       <%= @posts.each do |p| %>
       <div class="article">
           <h3 class="post_title"><%= link_to p.title, p %></h3>
           <p class="post_date"><%= p.created_at.strftime("%A,%b %d") %></p>
           <p class="content"><%= truncate(p.content, length: 400)  %></p>
       </div>
       <% end %>
   </div>

   <div class="button_wrapper">
       <a href="blog.html" class = "button">More Articles</a>
   </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
#posts {
    padding: 6.5em 0 10em 0;
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        color: $text;
        margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    }
    .post_container {
        padding: 6em 0 6em 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-start;
        .article {
            max-width: 28%;
        }
        .post_title {
            color: $text;
            font-size: 1.6em;
        }
        .post_date {
            padding: .75rem 0;
            color: $accent;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }
        .content {
            color: $grey;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your using `<%=` at the beginning of your loop. You would use `<%` instead

Change the `post_container` div to this:

```
<div class="post_container">
  <% @posts.each do |p| %>
    <div class="article">
      <h3 class="post_title"><%= link_to p.title, p %></h3>
      <p class="post_date"><%= p.created_at.strftime("%A,%b %d") %></p>
      <p class="content"><%= truncate(p.content, length: 400)  %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= @posts.each do |p| %>
```

Should be

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
```

Do not output the result of `.each`.

Comment: AH ha!! what a rookie mistake! thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
```

because <= %> use for print the value in your case it'll print the whole loop